# Manifest Merger Failed against application component factory

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, mapactivity

I am a beginner and using MapActivity for the first time, my project is generating some errors titled "manifest merger failed" and suggesting to add a line in the android manifest file

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-41:19 to override.
```

**This is the code from manifest file**

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application

        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

    <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**But after adding the suggested line in the manifest folder it has generated some different errors as shown below**

[This picture contains the error messages after adding the suggested line in android manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPM8y.pngthis)

Comment: Migrate to [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate)

Comment: how can i migrate to androidx